# Google Now "Shazam this song" not working

Tags: google, shazam

I'm trying to use this feature
https://support.shazam.com/hc/en-us/articles/205024298--Ok-Google-Shazam-this-song-

But when I try it just google searches "Shazam this song" like any other unrecognized phrase. I also tried "What's this song" and it said "Action not supported in your country"

I'm in Canada and have a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 6.0.1. I have Shazam installed, and reinstalling it didn't fix it.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shazam.android&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try holding your <kbd>home</kbd> button down for 3 seconds. When Google Assistant appears, ask your question. Same thing happened to me with sluggish responses from google now requests after the  6.0.1 update rolled out. Google Assistant taking over for Google Now going forward.